# How to simulate a submit event in Javascript or via YUI

Tags: javascript, dom-events, yui3

I'm using a form validator, that listens to submit events, but I decided to send an ajax post request with form fields, instead of form submission.

Now I don't know how to throw the submit event. YUI's node-event-simulate module can simulate only clicking and mouse events.

Comment: In jQuery (another Javascript lib) you can do something like `$('element').submit();` or `$('element').trigger('submit');`. Think you have something like that in YUI as well. However I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your validators `.validate()` method ;)